# Reload data in onOptionsItemSelected during fragment (same) transaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem about my Android application.
I've an activity with a fragment that have a list of elements (about a forum with ID) and an action bar with 2 button: refresh and new.
I want to send the current ID to the "new button" that open an intent to other activity.

The problem is: when in the fragment (ListTopic.java) I launch another (same) fragment (ListTopic.java) to open another forum (then with other ID), the "new button" have the same ID of previous forum and not new.

So, if I have opened forum with ID 33, when I click the subforum with ID 200, the new button have ever ID 33.

This is code where I take new forumId:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_topics, container, false);

    parent = new Forum();
    count = 10;

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    pkg = getActivity().getPackageName();
    forumId = bundle.getString(pkg + "FORUMID");
    user = bundle.getString(pkg + "USER");
    password = bundle.getString(pkg + "PASS");
    nome = bundle.getString(pkg + "NOME");
    parent = (Forum) bundle.getSerializable(pkg + "parent");
```

This is end of code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_topic, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_topic_update:
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        subForumList = new ArrayList<Forum>();
        TopicList asyncTopic = new TopicList();
        asyncTopic.execute();
        break;
    case R.id.menu_topic_new:
        Intent newTopic = new Intent(getActivity(), NewTopicActivity.class);
        newTopic.putExtra(pkg + "USER", user);
        newTopic.putExtra(pkg + "PASS", password);
        newTopic.putExtra(pkg + "FORUMID", forumId);

        startActivity(newTopic);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks a lot!